# How to get the row number if value is in this row and return it

Tags: c#, excel, return, epplus

I'm not sure I asked the right question.

Basically I want to go through all rows and check if the Value in Cells[row, 5] =  nrNummer. If it does, I want the row number like 30 in realrow and return it. I dont know how to return the number or if "for" is the wrong approach. Below is my code. Maybe someone knows how to do it

```
private static int GetRowExcel(string projectName)
    {
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bin))
        using (ExcelPackage excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(stream))
        {
            var ws = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets["Work"];

            string nrNummer = projectName.Split(' ').First();
            for (int row = 5; ws.Cells[row, 5].Value != null; row++)
            {
               if(ws.Cells[row, 5].Value.ToString()==nrNummer)
                { int realrow = row;
                }

            }
        }
        return realrow; //The name'realrow' does not exist in the current context
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better approach is to return immediately after you have found your value and not iterate further in the for loop:

```
private static int GetRowExcel(string projectName)
    {
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bin))
        using (ExcelPackage excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(stream))
        {
            var ws = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets["Work"];

            string nrNummer = projectName.Split(' ').First();
            for (int row = 5; ws.Cells[row, 5].Value != null; row++)
            {
               if(ws.Cells[row, 5].Value.ToString()==nrNummer)
                { 
                    return row;
                }

            }
        }
        return -1;  // return any value that shows that row is not found
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to wait your for loops to finish. If I understand your function, once you have found the value, you don't have to continue your search, and can directly return the value, for exemple, instead of :

```
if(ws.Cells[row, 5].Value.ToString()==nrNummer)
{
    int realrow = row;
}
```

You could simply :

```
if(ws.Cells[row, 5].Value.ToString()==nrNummer)
{
    return row;
}
```

And in the end, instead of `return realrow` you can juste `return -1` or whatever since this return will be triggered only if the searched value is not found.

Answer (score 0):

```
return realrow; //The name'realrow' does not exist in the current context
```

This error occurrs because you are declaring `int realrow` inside `if`...

Do something like this:

```
private static int GetRowExcel(string projectName)
    {
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bin))
        using (ExcelPackage excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(stream))
        {
            var ws = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets["Work"];

            string nrNummer = projectName.Split(' ').First();
            for (int row = 5; ws.Cells[row, 5].Value != null; row++)
            {
               if(ws.Cells[row, 5].Value.ToString()==nrNummer)
                { return row;
                }

            }
        }
        return -1; //The name'realrow' does not exist in the current context
    }
```

I've just declared int realrow = 0; outside of the if, in that way you can return it.

**EDIT:**

For problems of computer overhead, return row if enter in if, if not return -1 (row was not founded.)

Comment: The problem with this solution is, that the algorithm continues to iterate although the searched row is found resulting in unnecessary computing overhead

Comment: @CodePope Nice interpretation. Going to edit right now.

Comment: @T.Steph Glad you make it bro!